# VBA how to pass integer to range values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to simplify this function from the following

```
Public Sub freezeRow(sheetAct, sheetType As String, sheetRow As Integer)

sheetAct.Activate    'Activate sheet
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False 'Unfreeze all rows

Select Case sheetType
    Case "Sum"
        'Freeze the Summary spread sheet after row 9
        sheetAct.Range("10:10").Select

    Case "Data"
        'Freeze the Summary spread sheet after row 2
        sheetAct.Range("3:3").Select
End Select

ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True 'Freeze selected rows

End Sub
```

**to something like this**

```
Public Sub freezeRow(sheetAct, sheetType As String, sheetRow As Integer)

sheetAct.Activate    'Activate sheet
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False 'Unfreeze all rows

sheetAct.Range("sheetRow:sheetRow").Select


ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True 'Freeze selected rows

End Sub
```

I can't seem to remove the quotes in the `range` and when I run it tosses some obscure error

Comment: `"sheetRow:sheetRow"` should be `sheetRow & ":" & sheetRow"`

Comment: Maybe `sheetAct.Cells(sheetRow, 1).EntireRow.Select`.  Also - `sheetRow As Integer` - Integer will error after row 28000 something or other... use `sheetRow as Long`

Comment: `sheetAct.Rows(sheetRow).Select`

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure I'll make more rookie mistakes....new to VB

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `Cells()` all the time, since it's more explicit (to me anyways)

`sheetAct.Range("sheetRow:sheetRow").Select`

with

```
With sheetAct
    .Range(.Cells(sheetRow,1),.Cells(sheetrow,1)).EntireRow.Select
End with
```

Or, just use `sheetAct.Range(sheetRow & ":" & sheetRow).Select`

But why use `.Select`? You can [work around using `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) which is best practice. (Of course, if you're using it to double check you have the right range, then that's fine. It's when you work with the data you want to be careful).

Comment: The .Cells gives an unqualified reference error                   sheetAct.Range(.Cells(sheetRow, 1), .Cells(sheetRow, 1)).EntireRow.Select

Comment: @RickFlyFish - How is `sheetAct` sent to the sub? I'm assuming it's a `Worksheet`.  Also note the `.Range` does not start with `sheetAct.` using `With`, just use the `.` as a "place holder".

Answer (score 1):

As a quick solution, I suggest something like this:

```
Public Sub freezeRow(sheetAct As Worksheet, sheetRow As String)
  Application.Goto sheetAct.Rows(sheetRow)
  ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
  ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End Sub
```

You may add the line `ActiveWindow.Split = False` between the `ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False` and `ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True`, because if the `FreezePanes` was done after a `Split`, then `ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False` will change the window back to the `Split`-state as it was before. In that case `ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True` will ignore the selected range and freeze it at the point where the `Split` is located.

Also I suggest using `sheetAct.Rows(sheetRow + 1)` because the panes will be freezed over `sheetRow`. But that is just for a better logic `->` having `3` will freeze 3 rows instead if 2.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this method worked perfectly

```
Public Sub freezeRow(sheetAct, sheetRow As String)
  Dim rangeVal As String

   rangeVal = sheetRow & ":" & sheetRow
   sheetAct.Activate    'Activate sheet
   ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False 'Unfreeze all rows
   sheetAct.Range(rangeVal).Select 'Select appropriate row

   ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True 'Freeze selected rows
```

End Sub

This only for freezing Headers are visible while scrolling through the data